# yii2 Dimensions to be validated and display the error message in the form

Tags: error-handling, controller, yii2, bootstrap-modal, active-form

In yii2 project I have my own file structure setup. Anything uploaded will get saved as a file type. I can get the file dimensions using the file uploaded in the temp folder by yii2. Using those dimensions I set my own width and height and compare them. If the height and width is more than what I have declared It has display an error message in the form. Which I am unable to do it.

**My Active Form**

```
<div class="company-form">

    <?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action'=>['company/logo', 'id'=>$model->company_id],
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'options' => 
            ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data','class' => 'disable-submit-buttons','id'=> 'companyLogoForm'],
            'fieldConfig' => [
                'template' => "<div class=\"row\">
                <div class=\"col-xs-6 margin-top-8\">{label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-xs-6 text-right\">{hint}</div>
                \n<div class=\"col-xs-12 \">{input}</div>
                </div>",               
            ],                                        
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->errorSummary($model, $options = ['header'=>'','class'=>'pull-left']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->hiddenInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>

    <?= $form->field($file, 'file')->fileInput([])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Attach Logo'),['class'=> 'margin-top-8']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Save') : Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary','data' => ['disabled-text' => 'Please Wait']]) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**My Controller Action**

```
public function actionLogo($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

            $file = new File;
            $file->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
                $a = UploadedFile::getInstance($file,'file');
                $size = getimagesize($a->tempName);
                $maxWidth = 500;
                $maxHeight = 500;
                if ($size[0] > $maxWidth || $size[1] > $maxHeight)
                    {
                        $model->addError('file', $error = 'Error Message');
                      if($model->hasErrors()){
                          return ActiveForm::validate($model);
                      }

                    }

                $file->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($file,'file');
                $file->file_name = $file->file->name;
                $file->file_user = Yii::$app->user->id;
                $file->file_type = 1;

                if($file->save()){
                    $file->file_path = Files::getFilePath($file->file_id);
                    $validDir = $file->file->createFileDir($file->file_path, $file->file_id);

                    if($validDir){
                        $file->file->saveAs($file->file_path, false);
                        if($file->save()){
                            $model->company_file = $file->file_id;
                            $model->save();
                            return $this->redirect(['index']);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I add error message in the controller and pass that to display on my form on the modal box.

Note: my form is displayed on the modal box.

Thank you!!

Comment: use custom validation function in model rule.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the file processing in your model - or even better, create a specific `UploadForm` model for this purpose. 
In that case you can use File Validation or a custom validator to set errors during model validation.
The built-in `yii\validators\FileValidator` gives you plenty pf validation rules out of the box.

This is actually pretty well explained in the documentation: [Uploading Files](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html)

See also the documentation for [FileValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html)

Example for validating an uploaded image file:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $imageFile;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No the problem here is I have a file structure setup..by my own.. And when I upload image files it will be saved as a file type. The files in the file structure can be any file may be pdf, jpg and so on. The file validators don't have rules to limit the dimensions of a file. Say my file is an image file I want to get the dimensions comapre them with the dimensions I have set and pass error if the dimension is more than the set dimension

Comment: Sorry I misundertood that the errors were not visible in the model. Best approach would be to create your own custom file validator in that case and use this in your model; you could base it on `FileValidator` and add your own checks there

Answer (score 0):

Try this validation rule

```
['imageFile', 'image', 'minWidth' => 250, 'maxWidth' => 250,'minHeight' => 250, 'maxHeight' => 250, 'extensions' => 'jpg, gif, png', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2],
```

Comment: That is not possible because i am using a fileValidator. fileValidator doesn't have the minWidth and maxHeight attributes

Comment: corrected: my mistake, you can use image validator instead.